# how to read dynamic tsv file d3js

Tags: javascript, caching, servlets, d3.js, csv

I have to load some data stored in tsv file to create a bar chart with d3js.
I use this code to read the file:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
```

The data inside the file change at every click of a button that invokes a servlet function to update these data.

The problem is that I can't get the updating data, so I am stuck on the fist data stored in the file.

I avoid this problem creating n-files and reading these different files.

But I want to use the same file.

Answer (score 0):

So here you go,

1. Onclick get the new file
2. Once *you are sure* you have the updatedFile read it using d3.tsv (you can use **callback** here) and inside that give a call to the function which does drawing

Comment: This is what I am doing but it doesn't work. I get always the old values.

Comment: can you provide bit more detail on the code/design part or a fiddle if possible

Answer (score 0):

This is because your browser is caching the file and not actually reloading it. You can avoid this by adding a changing query parameter to the call, which doesn't do anything but prevents the browser from caching:

```
var counter = 0;
// ...
d3.tsv("data.tsv?foo=" + i++, function(error, data) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lars. With your advice the behavior has changed. Now it reads the correct value one time on five/six request. I have added this delay before calling the reading function: setTimeout(function(){update(xmlhttp.responseText);},3000);  Now it works